# $a/b=c$, how to move the numerator to the right side of the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given an equation of the form $a/b=c$, how do you move $a$, the numerator, over to the other side so that you get $b =c?$ (where $?$ denotes my ignorance of what the right side should look like).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
a/b &= c\\
a &= bc\\
b &= a/c
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but here is it worded.
You multiply the denominator out by multiplying both sides so: a/b = c becomes a/b*b = c*b. As you are multiplying the fraction by the denominator the denominator and the multiplier cancel out and you are left with a = bc. You cannot get rid of a letter but if you wanted b on one side then you would simply move c, to do this you factorise so its a = b(c). You then divide both sides by c, so then a/c = (b(c))/c. Then the c on the numerator and denominator cancel out so you will be left with a/c = b or rearrange to b = a/c.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b} & = c \\ \\
b \cdot \frac{a}{b} & = c \cdot b \\
\require{cancel} \\
\cancel{b} \cdot \frac{a}{\cancel{b}} & = c \cdot b \\ \\
a & = cb \\ \\
\frac{a}{c} & = \frac{cb}{c} \\ \\
\frac{a}{c} & = \frac{\cancel{c}b}{\cancel{c}} \\ \\
\frac{a}{c} & = b
\end{align}
$$